# How to set onDismiss/CancelListener for custom dialog outside the class?

Tags: java, android, dialog, customdialog

I want to finish the activity when custom dialog is cancelled or dismissed. But when I use .setOnDismissListener in other classes, it is never being reached inside. I've found several problems, but the solution was to override onDismiss method inside the customDialog class. But I do not need to override onDismiss method for every customDialog I create. What should I do?

This is the code I call in another class, but never receive message in log "setOnDismissListener".

```
customDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {                                                       
        Log.d(TAG, "setOnDismissListener");
    }
});
```

My CustomDialog class:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomDialog";

    public CustomDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
        super(context);

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);

        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setPadding(10, 50, 10, 10);
        textView.setText(title);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTextSize(20);

        Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setTypeface(boldTypeface);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder
                .setCustomTitle(textView)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog customDialog = builder.show();

        TextView messageText = customDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if (messageText != null) {
            messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            messageText.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "messageText is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you finish the activity when the dialog is clicked and dismissed by the user?

Comment: That's what I am trying to achieve... How to do it?

Comment: Where do you create the dialog, can you post that code. That's from where I can help you.

Comment: CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(FirstActivity.this, "Title", "Message"); Or do I need to post all the CustomDialog class?

Comment: Yeah, you need because we also need to see the differences you know. If you can, that would be great :)

Comment: Great, let me see!

Comment: Check my answer, and see if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so if you are not using some API to parse information, or are using local variables I suggest you do whatever functionality you want to do in your onClickListener() Method.

> The problem is that you are using your CustomDialog which itself extends the Dialog Class. But instead of using that you create a new alert dialog and build that. You dismiss it, but the dialog which is dismissed is not your custom dialog class, but the builder dialog you created in your constructor. Even if you fixed for that, it introduces unnecessary complications.

What I suggest you do is create the Intent in your onClickListener() function. The way to do that would be to change your constructor to support a callback listener. Simply put you cannot just add an onDismissListener() when the dialog you listen to is another one. What you can do is pass in the function that you want to do when the user dismisses the dialog as a special case. See below.

1. So, first, modify your constructor like this:

   ```
   public CustomDialog(Context context, String title, String message, 
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
        super(context);
   }
   ```
2. In your constructor paste your previous code:

   ```
   TextView textView = new TextView(context);
   textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
   textView.setPadding(10, 50, 10, 10);
   textView.setText(title);
   textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
   textView.setTextSize(20);

   Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
   textView.setTypeface(boldTypeface);

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   builder
           .setCustomTitle(textView)
           .setMessage(message)
           .setPositiveButton("Ok", listener);

   AlertDialog customDialog = builder.show();

   TextView messageText = customDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
   if (messageText != null) {
       messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
       messageText.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
   } else {
       Log.w(TAG, "messageText is null");
   }
   ```

   What you do is where you used to create a new onClickListener() you pass in the listener parameter.
3. Go to your MainActivity or where you create your custom dialog. There do this:

   ```
   CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(FirstActivity.this, "Title", "Message", 
   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              //Do your functionality here.
              Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity.class);
              //Add any flags if you want
              ...
              context.startActivity(intent);

              //Or you can simply do context.finish();
       }
   });
   ```

   When you don't want to pass a onClickListener()(meaning when you don't want to `finish()` the activity) pass in `null`.

It would work. If this is not what you wanted, tell me and I will fix it.

Comment: That is working perfectly if someone presses OK on the dialog. What if they press outside the dialog and it disappears? Should I create add new listener as a parameter or is it possible to accomplish it with one listener? And if yes, with what?

Comment: Instead of onClickListener I used OnDismissListener and added the line: builder.setOnDismissListener(dismissListener); It's working perfectly now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface like

```
interface OnUserInformedCallback {
    fun positive()

    fun negative()
}
```

and implement this in your activity and pass it to the dialog method from where you are gettingdialog and you will get callback of ok and cancle in you activity.
code is like that

```
 fun alertDialog(
        context: Context,
        message: String,
        positiveText: String,
        isUa: Boolean,
        callback: OnUserInformedCallback
): Dialog {
    val dialog = Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout)
    dialog.window?.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
    dialog.setCancelable(true)
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
    val tvOk: TextView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.visit)
    val tvMsg: TextView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.mess)
    tvMsg.text = message
    tvOk.text = positiveText
    dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cancel).setOnClickListener {
        callback.negative()
    }
    tvOk.setOnClickListener {
        callback.positive()
    }
    dialog.create()
    return dialog
}
```

in java for default dialog

```
private AlertDialog getDialog(Activity context, String message, OnUserInformedCallback  callbac) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(R.string.app_name).setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, (dialog12, which) -> callbac.positive())
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.yes, (dialog1, which) -> callbac.positive())
        .create();
}
```

Comment: He wants it in java, so this is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But still you are creating not custom dialog. With default 'Dialog' it is working either way, but when I use my custom dialog, it doesn't reach the setOnDismissListener nor setOnCancelListener. Haven't tried with setOnClickListener, but that's not what I am trying to achieve. Plus this is in Kotlin, I am looking for Java.

Comment: @cjacky475 i added code in java also please try this.